# Appending a key value pair to an array of dictionary based on a condition javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, data-structures

I have an array of dictionaries

```
var nodes =
{
A: {'name' : 'A'},
B:{'name' : 'B'},
C:{'name' : 'C'},
D:{'name' : 'D'}
E:{'name' : 'E'}}
```

and

another array

```
var X_Group = ['A', 'B'];
```

I need to iterate through each of the dictionary elements and append group key with value X to them if it is present in the array X_Group and Y otherwise.
ie.

```
var nodes =
{
A: {'name' : 'A' , group :'X'},
B:{'name' : 'B', group :'X'},
C:{'name' : 'C', group :'Y'},
D:{'name' : 'D', group :'Y'},
E:{'name' : 'E', group :'Y'}
}
```

I have tried:

```
  for (var key in nodes){
    if (key in X_Group)
      nodes[key].group = 'X';
else 
      nodes[key].group = 'Y';
  }

But it does not work. Any suggestions  on how to fix the issue?
```

Comment: `nodes` is an ***`Object`*** (which is not quite the same as `Array`), `X_Group` is invalid JavaScript notation (its neither an `Object`, nor `Array`). However, if both were arrays, you could've do something, like `nodes.map(o => ({[o.name]:{...o, group: X_Group.includes(o.name) ? 'X' : 'Y'}}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `nodes` is ***an `Object`*** rather than array, and `X_Group` is an array, you may:

- rebuild your `nodes` array, using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- pass to `Object.assign()` (as its second parameter) [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) array ([`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) of `nodes` key-value pairs, appended with `group` property, having `'X'`/`'Y'` value based on whether it is found (with [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)) within `X_Group`

```js
const nodes = {A:{'name':'A'},B:{'name':'B'},C:{'name':'C'},D:{'name':'D'},E:{'name':'E'}},
      X_Group = ['A', 'B'],
      
      result = Object.assign(
        {},
        ...Object
          .keys(nodes)
          .map(key =>
            ({[key]: {
              ...nodes[key], 
              group: X_Group.includes(nodes[key].name) ? 'X' : 'Y'
            }})))
            
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. it worked. Could you suggest me the website from which I could learn more on this?

Comment: @Rao : You're most welcome, check out updated version of my answer with all the related references

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 'in' to check if a value is in an array. Use indexOf instead, which will return the index of the element, or -1.

Use this condition:

```
  if(X_Group.indexOf(nodes[key].name)!==-1)
```

Comment: sorry, I have updated the question. The dictionary has the key same as the name.

Comment: Is X_Group an array [] or an object {} ? Also make sure you post code that actually compile, and add the actual output, to compare against the expected one.

Comment: it is an array [ ]